# gcloud dns managed-zones list along with record-sets count format

Tags: format, output, gcloud, google-cloud-dns

In the output of `gcloud dns managed-zones list` ,I want to show the name of  `dnsName, creationTime, name, networkName, visibility` and the count of `recrod-sets` in each `hosted-zone`.
I used below command to get two output in two commands
#get hosted-zone and other values

`gcloud dns managed-zones list --format='table(dnsName, creationTime:sort=1, name, privateVisibilityConfig.networks.networkUrl.basename(), visibility)'`

#get record-sets for a hostedzone

`gcloud dns record-sets list --zone=$zoneName |awk 'NR>1{print}'|wc -l`

I think I can get this in a shell script by getting a list of hosted zone and then printing two output together.
But is there a better way to do in a single `gcloud` command ?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC (!?), you'll need to issue both `gcloud` commands as each provides distinct data.

To your point, you should be able to easily combine the combine the commands using a shell script and iterating over each zone from `managed-zones list`, to issue `record-sets list --zone=${i}`.

If you'd like help, please include dummy data from the 2 commands and I'll draft something for you.

Comment: Thansk @dazWilkin, I'll do thatI
I was just looking if someone has  done in a single command using some hack.